# Is Android WifiP2pManager.discoverServices able to discover NsdServiceInfo (by NsdManager.registerService)?

Tags: android, wifip2p, nsd

step 1:

```
nsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, registrationListener);
```

step 2:

```
p2pManager.discoverServices(p2pChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int code) {
        ...
    }
});
```

So, is step 2 able to discover step 1's service?